# Unity3D how does AssetBundle cache work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am kinda confused about:

After downloading an assetbundle at the first time, how Unity knows I have already downloaded it and directly load from cache(disk) at the second time?

Does it use url to mapping to local storage? If in that case, if I update my assetbundle on the server using the same name, at the second time, it will still be loading from cache since the url doesn't change?

Sample code:

```
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest request = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(uri, 0);
yield return request.Send();
//only download at the first time, at the second time, it can be loaded from cache
AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(request);
GameObject cube = bundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>("Cube");
```

Answer (score 2):

To have caching;

Instead of calling:

```
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest request = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(uri, 0);
```

You must call GetAssetBundle with a version number:

```
UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest request = UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(uri, 1, 0);
```

See documentation here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle.html

You can also implement this with a call to `new DownloadHandlerAssetBundle(string url, uint version, uint crc);`. See sample code here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle-ctor.html
And documentation here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle-ctor.html

Note that when you use caching, the `request.responseCode` will no longer be value `200` (success), but will be 0, when the data is retrieved from cache!